# How to pass data from number of sheets in a workbook with the help of dataprovider

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I like to pass test data from number of sheets in a workbook with the help of data provider.Means i like to run one test case from one sheet and another test case from another sheet.Is it possible through dataprovider?

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried and what the error is. This questions is WAY too broad as it is and is likely a duplicate of a number of other questions that make up all the parts to get this working. You should spend some time googling your own question, try writing some code to accomplish this, and then come back and clarify your question if you run into issues.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the DataProviders that SeLion offers -- http://selion.io

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code as it has been programmed for a single sheet yet you can implement it for multiple sheet using [getNumberOfSheets](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getNumberOfSheets%28%29) keyword.

The following is a code that works fine for me

```
static Object[][] myObject = null;

    @DataProvider(name = "Authentication")
    public static Object[][] credentials() { 

        FileInputStream file;
        try {
            String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\needful\\Book1.xlsx";
            System.out.println(filePath);

            file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            int noOfrepeat = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println("Test Repeat time " + noOfrepeat);

            short noOfData = row.getLastCellNum();
            System.out.println("No of Test Data " + noOfData);

            myObject = new Object[noOfrepeat][noOfData];

            int repeat_int = 0;
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                String str = null;
                int data_int = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        str = "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        str = "" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        str = "" + cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                    }

                    myObject[repeat_int][data_int] = str;

                    System.out.println("repeat_int:" + repeat_int + " data_int:" + data_int + " - "
                            + myObject[repeat_int][data_int]);

                    data_int++;

                }
                System.out.println("");

                repeat_int++;

            }

            file.close();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\needful\\output.xlsx"));

            workbook.write(out);
            workbook.close();
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myObject;
    }

    // Here we are calling the Data Provider object with its Name
    @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")
    public void test(String sUsername, String sPassword, String str) {

        System.out.println(sUsername + " , " + sPassword + " , " + str);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, by using different Dataproviders for different test methods

```
@Test(dataProvider="dp1")
public void testMethod1() {
    //Method body here
}

@Test(dataProvider="dp2")
public void testMethod2() {
   // Method body here
}

@DataProvider(name="dp1") 
public Object[][] dataProvider1{

   // Logic for DataProvider 1 here (return data from sheet 1)
}

@DataProvider(name="dp2") 
public Object[][] dataProvider2{

   // Logic for DataProvider 2 here (return data from sheet 2)
}
```

Comment: I am not using different test methods .Using one dataprovider i need to test data from different page.

Comment: In that case it can be achieved by merging two Dataproviders in one Dataprovider and use the merged dataprovider